# Connection to mainframe and Unix to get certificate information

Tags: powershell, unix, x509certificate, mainframe

I have a program that works good to get certificate information, but only for Windows boxes. I need it to work for UNIX and mainframe. I added the cert to the Windows trusted root cert auth and have the root cert there as well. I did not generate my own cert here as I didn't think it was needed.

It blows up on the last line where it does an auth, with the error

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Any ideas what to check for?

```
$certpath = "C:\Certdir\Certificates\xxx.cer"

$cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::CreateFromCertFile($certPath)

[System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols]$protocol = "TLS"

$certcol = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection
$certcol.Add($cert)

$socket = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient($computerName, $port)
$stream = $socket.GetStream()
$sslStream = New-Object System.Net.Security.SslStream $stream,$false
$sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient($computerName,$certcol,$protocol,$false)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is here. Do you want to *fetch* a certificate from a remote host, (as your subject says) or do you want to *authenticate* against a remote host (as your code says)? Did you verify the validity of the remote certificate?

Comment: The end goal is to fetch a cert from a remote host, from MVS and AIX. I THINK I need to authenticate first, which will give me the correct  connection, which I can then query for cert info.  If there is a better or different way.. I am all ears.  Also yes I did verify the remote cert. thanks.

Comment: That is not how [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake) works. Also, what do you need the certificates for, i.e. *why* do you want to fetch them?

Comment: I am getting expire information and creating reports based on expire date. The actual part of the code dealing with the cert is not shown. I have it and its working well for Windows.  How does TLS work then? thanks.